# Antlr3 AST creation : how to test an optional subrule?

Tags: parsing, antlr, bison, antlr3, abstract-syntax-tree

I am looking for a way to know if an optional sub rule has been used or not. For example:

```
my_rule returns [node* n = 0]:
  (v = (optional_subrule)?)
  {
    $n = new node($v ? $v.n : MY_DEFAULT_VALUE);
  }
;
```

But this does not work. I tried many ways to write it and nothing seems to be possible without writing code...

```
my_rule returns [node* n = new node()]:
  ((optional_subrule { n->set_subrule(...); })?)
;
```

And when you have a bison background, you like having your ast node constructors at the end of your rules... And it decreases the readability (imagine a much more bigger rule).

Does anyone know something I missed ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ANTLR does not allow such a feature. The solution [proposed by Bart Kiers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6024241/antlr3-ast-creation-how-to-test-an-optional-subrule/6027584#6027584) must not be used since it results in an undefined behavior code.

So I had to rewrite the rules as :

```
my_rule returns [node* n = 0]
@init
{
  type temporary_variable = init_value;
}:
  (v = optional_subrule { temporary_variable = $v.result; })?
  mandatory_subrule
  {
    $n = new node(temporary_variable, $mandatory_subrule.result);
  }
;
```

We now have the advantage of a **well-initialised** variable, and we still have only one node constructor with every arguments needed.